# accessing content of Hbase data in a jsp page

Tags: hbase

How to access the content of data stored in Hbase in a jsp page so that it can be displayed in a web browser . data stored in Hbase can be of various types like images , textual data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Phoenix is a relational database layer over HBase delivered as a client-embedded JDBC driver targeting low latency queries over HBase data. Apache Phoenix takes your SQL query, compiles it into a series of HBase scans, and orchestrates the running of those scans to produce regular JDBC result sets. The table metadata is stored in an HBase table and versioned, such that snapshot queries over prior versions will automatically use the correct schema. Direct use of the HBase API, along with coprocessors and custom filters, results in performance on the order of milliseconds for small queries, or seconds for tens of millions of rows.

I am not familiar with jsp, but using phoenix code in java you easily access hbase.